# Repeat if array, display if string

Tags: angularjs

I am referencing a value in my controller that may be a string or an array. If it's an array, I want to use "ng-repeat" (probably) to list out my items.

If it's a string, I just want to display the string.

Something like:

```
<div>
    {{if is array}}
        <span ng-repeat="v in myvalue">{{v}}</span>
    {{else}}
        {{myvalue}}
    {{endif}}
</div>
```

I'm wondering if there's an elegant way to do this in Angularjs that I'm simply not yet familiar with.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [angular.isArray](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isArray) method. You can use that. You need to place it in the the scope or vm:

```
$scope.isArray = angular.isArray
```

And in HTML

```
 <span ng-repeat="v in myvalue" ng-if="isArray(myvalue)">{{v}}</span>
 <span ng-if="!isArray(myvalue)">{{myvalue}}</span>
```

If you are using it in more than one place, best is to go for a directive.

Comment: what's with the `if` in the interpolation? How does that create expected output?

Comment: @charlietfl Angular can interpolate conditionals.

Comment: @jusopi fine but wouldn't produce expected results that way... it does now after edit

Comment: agreed, plus he's modified his answer so it's a moot point now

Comment: All great answers IMO, but this was the best solution for me

Answer (score 1):

Do the logic on the controller (assign to a different variable for array and string) - then just do the dumb logic in the view:

```
if (Array.isArray($scope.myvalue)) {
    $scope.myArray = $scope.myvalue;
} else {
    $scope.myString = $scope.myvalue;
}
```

And the view

```
<div>
    <div ng-if="myArray">
        <span ng-repeat="v in myArray">{{v}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="myString">
        {{myString}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

make a simple getter

```
$scope.getVal = function( vals ){
    if(Array.isArray(vals)) return vals
    else return [ vals ]
}
```

then instead of ng-if **AND** ng-repeat just use the repeater as you normally would.

```
<div ng-repeat="val in getVal(vals)"> {{ val }} </div>
```

Comment: There's a nuance to my specific situation where this won't work, but I can see how it would in others. Upvote

Comment: Can you explain the specifics?

Comment: I'm actually wrapping the array elements in another element that won't be present with the string value, as there's additional user interaction with the elements created by the array.

Comment: Ahhh ok I see.  In that case I would drive this by a filter and use the ng-if.  I really dislike adding this kind of logic to the controllers.